# $\rho_\gamma(X)=\frac{1}{\gamma} \log \mathbb{E}[e^{-\gamma X}]$

Tags: probability, measure-theory, random-variables, expectation, correlation

$\rho_\gamma(X)=\frac{1}{\gamma} \log \mathbb{E}[e^{-\gamma X}]$

is a convex risk measure, but it fails the subadditivity property in order to be called coherent.

A mapping $\rho:L^\infty(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is called a coherent risk measure if the following properties hold

If $X \geq 0$ then $\rho(X)\leq 0$.

Subadditivity: $\rho(X_1+X_2)\leq \rho(X_1)+\rho(X_2)$

Positive homogeneity: for $\lambda \geq 0$ we have  $\rho(\lambda X)=\lambda\rho(X) $

Translation Invariance:  For all $ c\in \mathbb{R}$
$\rho(X+c)=\rho(X)-c$

Im trying to investigate why it fails, or better, under which condition it is not true.
\begin{align*}
\rho_\gamma(X_1+X_2) & = \frac{1}{\gamma}\log\mathbb{E}[e^{-\gamma(X_1 + X_2)}]\\
& = \frac{1}{\gamma}\log\mathbb{E}[e^{-\gamma X_1}e^{-\gamma X_2}]
\end{align*}
at this stage I am a bit stuck, becasue I think it depends on how $X_1$ and $X_2$ are correlated to continue.. hm any help would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cauchy-Schwarz inequality shows that $\rho_\gamma(2X)\geqslant2\rho_\gamma(X)$ for every random variable $X$ and every positive $\gamma$, and that the inequality is strict as soon as $X$ is not almost surely constant.

Thus, subadditivity and positive homogeneity both fail.

Comment: Thanks! Am I assuming correctly that you used Jensen http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality $\frac{1}{\gamma}\log\mathbb{E}[e^{-\gamma 2 X}] \geq \frac{1}{\gamma}\log(\mathbb{E}[e^{-\gamma X}])^2 $

Comment: would you please elaborate a bit on the fact that the inequality is strict for all non constant X. ( almost surely ). Thanks  in advance!

Comment: As written in the post this uses Cauchy-Schwarz inequality (which of course is a special case of Jensen inequality). About the strictness of the inequality: once again, as written in the post, this is due to the fact that Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $E(XY)^2\leqslant E(X^2)E(Y^2)$ is strict except for almost surely proportional random variables $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: makes sense, thanks for your help and patience